# Getting access to localhost by using webservice in my Android device

Tags: android, web-services

I'm trying to test an Android aplication that uses webservice to access localhost.

My device ip is 192.168.0.21 and my localhost ip is 192.168.0.22.

I tried this:

```
HttpsURLConnection conn;
Url url = new URL("http://192.168.0.22:80/admapp/adm_service.php?");
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

It does not work. I've tried to disable the firewall and nothing.
I'm using EasyPHP, but I think that this don't matter.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Check this URL in post Man ya Advance Rest Client.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you map your IP to localhost in hosts file. The file will be at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in windows, /etc/hosts in Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that too, does not work yet.